# Laravel how to use style in Html facade

Tags: php, laravel, styles

there I want to use a Laravel Collective Html to navigation on my page using ids and styles how do I implement this.. 
The point is user clicks a link "show weaning details" and other hidden fields appear.
Below is my code that is not working.

```
{{ Html::link('', 'Show Weaning details', array('id' => 'showWeaning','style' => 'display: none')) }}
```

Comment: Your code is not "working" because it doesn't do anything. You should do some javascript working...

Comment: from [docs](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html#generating-urls) the function is  `link_to()`  not `link()`

Comment: thanks, I will take a look

Answer (score 0):

Use [**link_to**](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html)

```
{{ Html::link_to('foo/bar', 'Show Weaning details', [ 'id' => 'showWeaning','style' => 'display: none'] ) }}
```